# How to run multiple storm topology at the same instance?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I am learning storm.I have a doubt regarding the number of topology we can run at a time on Apache Storm.I have submitted two topologies on storm cluster but at a time only one topology runs.I need to KILL or DEACTIVATE the already present topology to run any new topology.

I am using Storm 0.9.4

Zookeeper 3.4.6

Kafka 2.10-0.8.2.1

I am running one instance of storm nimbus,supervisor and ui.

Do I need to run multiple instances of each?

What do I need to do to run multiple topologoies at the same time?

I am attaching the screenshot of my storm ui.

[image: Storm UI]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using only 2 supervisor.slots.ports(in storm.yaml).And setNumWorkers() in my topology configuration was also specified as 2.Hence,the topology which was running first was occupying both the slots. Now, I have set 5 supervisor.slots.ports and things are working fine.I am able to run multiple topologies at a time.

Comment: Did you set it on the `storm.yaml` of the server Nimbus is on or on all the other servers that the supervisor is running? If you configure `storm.yaml` on 5 supervisors to have 5 slots each, will you be able to run 5*5=25 topologies?

Comment: @Nav You need to set `supervisor.slots.ports` on the supervisor machines.Yes, you should be able to run.Make sure you set the number of workers in topology accordingly

Comment: So by default if each supervisor has 4 slots, then 5 supervisors should have 5*4=20 slots without configuring `storm.yaml`. But that doesn't happen. I was only able to run 4 topologies. The 5th topology got 0 workers (this is having 5 supervisors and without editing `storm.yaml`). Even another person had the same problem: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/wLOq1nImRWQ

Comment: you need to configure storm.yaml on all the supervisor machines and set supervisor.slots.ports there. For example, if you have 5 supervisor machines then you need to have storm.yaml on all the 5 machines and you need to edit it to include supervisor slots.

Comment: Also, make sure you set `setNumWorkers()` in you storm topology accordingly.If that exceeds the number of supervisor ports then the topology running first will occupy all the slots leaving nothing for the rest